# Core Data is not persisting even after context.save()

Tags: ios, swift, storage

I am saving different activities to Core Data. While the app is working i can easily retrieve this data. But after the app I closed the data is gone even if even after I explicitly save it using `context.save()`. Any ideas why this happens?

```
private func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func retrieveTestEntity() -> TestEntity? {
    let managedContext = getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TestEntity")
    
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [TestEntity]
        
        if result.count > 0 {
            // Assuming there will only ever be one Entity in the app.
            return result[0]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Retrieving user failed. \(error): \(error.userInfo)")
        return nil
    }
}

func saveActivity(_ activity: Activity) {
    let managedContext = getContext()
    guard let testEntity = retrieveTestEntity() else { return }
    
    testEntity.activity.append(activity)
    
    do {
        print("Saving session...")
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to save session data! \(error): \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Straight away I can see an issue; what if there is more than one entity in your data store?  You return `nil` and add another entity, making the problem worse. You should add some better error handling in that `else` clause. At least print a message. You could also invert the test; return `nil` if the result array `isEmpty` other wise return the first element.

Comment: thanks, i did it intentionally for my internal test. I create just 1 entity for this test and was trying to save an array of Activities in it. I'll definitely fix it in a real app where i am going to use it.